# Books/ biography about the Ketzos and his learning methodology

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, jewish-books, torah-study, aryeh-leib-heller

Does anyone know of any noteworthy books/ biographies on [R' Aryeh Leib HaCohen Heller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Leib_HaCohen_Heller) (1745 – 1812) author of the *Ketzos Hachoshen*, *Avnei Miluim*, and [*Shev Shmaytsa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shev_Shema%27tata)- that explain his learning methodology and approach to learning Talmud?

(doesn't necessarily **have** to be a biography)

Preferably in English but Hebrew also welcome- thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One such work is Rabbi Daniel Mann's *[A Glimpse of Greatness: A Study in the Works of Giants of Lomdus](http://www.ktav.com/index.php/ktav/a-glimpse-at-greatness.html)*, which was reviewed [here](https://jewishaction.com/books/reviews/glimpse-greatness/). There is also a Hebrew biography titled *Shnei Keruvim* by Meir Herskowitz, about the Ketzos and the Tosfos Yom Tov.

Comment: That looks like an awesome book!

Comment: Worth noting that Hershkowitz’s book also contains an English side entitled ‘Guardians of the Faith’. (IIRC it’s more a biography and less explaining their learning.)